# Checking whether relations are equal to foreign fields using LINQ Any()

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Can you find a more understandable way to write the following one-liner?

```
Enumerable.Range(0, relation.Fields.Count).
           Any(i => relation.Fields[i] != relation.ForeignFields[i])
```

but still preserving its brevity?

Simply put, I wanna cycle on `relation.Fields` collection to see if their `string` elements are one-by-one equal to `relation.ForeignFields` ones.

The reason I had to use `Enumerable.Range` is that I need an index, in order to cycle the two collections.

Note: they have for sure the same count.

---

I wrote an [extension method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135611/31988) based on [@t3chb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135605/31988)

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Pimgd In spite of my little reputation on CodeReview, I have plenty on StackOverflow and I know how to behave on StackExchange.

Comment: @Pimgd The fact is that my edit was not a complete answer, so I didn't post it as a self-answer, but accepted t3chb0t's one instead.

Comment: That's great. We have slightly different rules here, please read them. What you did was not so much wrong as that it risks reviewers reviewing your newly added code, which creates a problematic cycle as some answers refer to revision 1 and others to revision 2. Thus we rollback - not because it is wrong to want to say what you did, but to prevent reviewers from wasting their time.

Comment: @Pimgd Ok, I got it. But I still think it would have been useful for future readers.

Comment: one option would be post a self answer (with reasoning included, not just a code dump), link to it in the question, leave the accept as is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not realy shorter then your example but it will work with any enumerable and does not require a count/length to be known:

```
var any = Fields
    .Select((field, i) => new { filed, i })
    .Any(x => x.field != relation.ForeignFields[x.i])
```

---

I think this might work as well if both collections are in sync:

```
var any = Fields.Zip(relation.ForeignFields, (x, y) => x != y).Any(z => z);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK, `Any` does not support **index** as second lambda parameter, only `Select` does.

Comment: Ok, now that you've edited the answer, it's ok.

Comment: @Teejay I thought it would so I checked it and fixed the example.

Comment: @Teejay I noticed it at the same time as you've commented ;-)

Comment: Ok, anyway I was looking for something even easier, but probably you're right when saying that "this is the shortest"...

Comment: What do you think is more understandable? I think they are similar...

Comment: I think I'll need to change my mind... now after the edit it's not the shortest any more. It might be different and does not depend on a fixed count/length but it's not shorter.

Comment: This will work with any IEnumerable, your code however requries a count/index to be known.

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste or usage. I don't see any other _optimizations_. It's a pity that `Any` does not provide an index.

Comment: I've added another edit.

Comment: Yes that's true. My way requires count to be known.

Comment: Your **zip** way is interesting thoug I think a small number of devs know how it works.

Comment: I ended up writing an extension method Any that also provides indexing, based on your first anwser, so I accepted it. Please check out my edit, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Can you not simply do SequenceEqual?

```
var list = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" };

var areListsEqual = list.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

Comment: @Hosch250 it (code by asker) seems to check if any not matches - so if all match.

Comment: Thanks, dindn't know about this one. I'll use it for the particular case.
This wouldn't be applicable if the lambda condition was different though, so my accepted answer will remain the current one. Anyway, I upvoted.

Comment: Ah, right.  Removed my comment.

Comment: If you wanted to play with the elements afterward, you can also do list.Except(list2) or vice versa.

Comment: This also has a different meaning than the example in @Teejay's question. The original code checks whether `Fields` is a *prefix* of `ForeignFields`, not whether they're equal.

Comment: @AlexReinking Actually, I specified that they have the same length (by design, in fact they are fields of a DB relation, one list represents fields on the child table, one on the parent)

Comment: @Teejay -- ah, I must have missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@t3chb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135605), I ended up writing an extension method `Any` that also provides indexing:

```
public static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, int, bool> lambda)
{
    return enumerable.Select((el, ix) => new { el, ix }).Any(x => lambda(x.el, x.ix));
}
```

Use:

```
relation.Fields.Any((f, ix) => f != relation.ForeignFields(ix))
```

That way, code in the main software remains concise and understandable.

---

I wrote an `All` version as well:

```
public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, int, bool> lambda)
{
    return enumerable.Select((el, ix) => new { el, ix }).All(x => lambda(x.el, x.ix));
}
```